# Русские начали наступление... (= наступали). Можно ли на этом основании считать "начали наступление" СИС?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, тип-сказуемого

Можно ли при затруднении в определении типа и объёма сказуемого использовать приём возможной замены его параллельной конструкцией? Является ли такой способ универсальным для определения предикативного признака подлежащего?

Comment: Иван, на сайте принято отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец понял, учту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод замены применять **нельзя,** так как мы получим **разные** синтаксические конструкции при обозначении сходной семантики (синтаксическая синонимия). Нужно провести **грамматический анализ** сказуемого в заданном предложении.

Сравним два варианта: *Русские **начали наступление / начали наступать.***

1. *Русские **начали** (что?)  наступление.*

***Начали***. Простое глагольное сказуемое. Грамматическая связь: беспредложное управление В.п., ***наступление*** – прямое дополнение.

2. *Русские **начали наступать.***

***Начали наступать.*** Составное глагольное сказуемое (***СГС***):  фазовый глагол ***начать*** + основной глагол в форме инфинитива ***наступать***.

Сравнить:
*Полк был **в наступлении**.  Русские были **в наступлении.***
Это ***СИС***: основная  связка был  + именная часть ***в наступлении***  (предложно-падежная форма).

Пример: Боевые машины 1-го Белорусского ***были в наступлении*** с июня 44-го и выработали свой ресурс.

Таким образом, надо хорошо знать все виды сказуемых.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**[Виды составных сказуемых](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)** (стр. 67 – 73)

**[Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)**

**НАЧАТЬ**, -чну, -чнёшь; начал, -ла, -ло; начатый; -чат, -а, -о; св. 1. что и с инф. Приступить к какому-л. действию. Н. лекцию, репетицию, арию, обед. Н. учить уроки, купаться, пахать землю. Н. лаять, мяукать. Н. спорить, ругаться, говорить.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149170/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.